# How to use the arguments of "_init_ " in other methods?

Tags: python, init

I want to use one parameter 'term' in my `_init_` method.As you can see, when the `_init` method get this parameter, I want to use it as the name of my database's collection and insert data into it. But I don't know how to use the value of `term` from `_init` in the whole class.So does anybody have good advice for me to deal with this?

```
class EPGDspider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "EPGD"
        allowed_domains = ["epgd.biosino.org"]

    db = DB_Con()
    collection = db.getcollection(term)

    def __init__(self, term=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EPGDspider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = ['http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/textsearch.jsp?textquery=%s&submit=Feeling+Lucky' % term]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]|//tr[@class="even"]')
        url_list = []
        base_url = "http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD"

        for site in sites:
            item = EPGD()
            item['description'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract())
            self.collection.update({"genID": item['genID']}, dict(item), upsert=True)
            yield item
```

Comment: Before writing classes, you should read and study at least the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) on that subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it an [instance variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables):

```
def __init__(self, term=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EPGDspider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.term = term
    # ...
```

Then, reference it using `self.term` in other methods:

```
def parse(self, response):
    print(self.term)
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!